# HttpResponse java

Tags: java, android

como tratar a resposta json do servidor?

```
HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  

String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responsePOST.getEntity());
```

A String "responseBody" vem do php assim `{"product":[{"id":"21","cliente":"","descricao":""},{"id":"22","cliente":"","descricao":""},{"id":"19","cliente":null,"descricao":"Celular"},{"id":"17","cliente":"Fddh","descricao":"Fdf"}],"success":1}`

Como eu transformo essa String em Strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a API de JSON do Java. A partir da String no formato JSON, é possível construir uma representação em memória e extrair os dados que precisa:

```
HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responsePOST.getEntity());

try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);

     // Recupera a lista product do JSON
    JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray("product");

    Integer success = json.getInt("success");

    int length = products.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = product.getString("id");
        String cliente = product.getString("cliente");
        String descricao = product.getString("descrição");

        // Sua logica com os campos
    }
} catch(JSONException e){}
```

É possível usar a biblioteca da GSON da Google. Que usa reflection para popular objetos POJO a partir do JSON. Mas acredito que essa abordagem já resolva o problema.

Mais informações de uma olhada na documentação: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Boa @Wakim funcionou muito bem! muito obrigado cara.